# Why sometimes Network Analyst can not find the shortest or the best route?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, route, vertices

Normally in Network analyst and route detection it has to find the shortest and efficient way.But here in my work I can see that it does not find the best choice.I wonder why it chose the longer path ? 
I have to mention that I am working on geological part of an area and I want to know the shortest connection between available fractures!
Would it be because lots of vertices? or anything is wrong there that it cannot solve the route?
Below you can see one of the examples of my project!
[image]

Comment: I can think of two possibilities right off - the quality of the network data (ie overlapping or not truly snapped lines, missing connections, 3D lines) and the analysis configuration (by distance with any other attributes?). It is difficult to see in your image, are all points connected by lines? I can see some, but other areas it doesn't look like they are. How was the network created - was a topology used to verify geometry? Could you post an image of your analysis configuration dialog or describe what settings you have used?

Comment: I create the network such as below process:
gdb file / new feature Dataset / Import the digitized lines to feature dataset/ then right click on dataset and made new network... 
in dialog box I answered :
Do ou want to model turn in this network ? YES
Connectivity : one time to enr point / one time to any vertex
How would you like to model the elevation of your network feature? None

Comment: I should clarify: network creation settings can be important, but I was actually asking how you created the lines used in the network. I see from one of your other questions that you (manually?) digitized them from a hillshade. The question is the quality of those lines - do they overlap, go back on themselves, snap endpoint to endpoint, have any z values as opposed to just x,y? Basically, the possible reason it doesn't take the shortest route is the network lines that appear to be shortest in 2D top down view actually aren't geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, there are some gaps. Try to create new Topology with rule "must have not dangles" for your network and validate it.